# При преобразовании JSON в объектный тип данных json_value возвращает неинициализированный экземпляр объекта

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle19c

В 19c появилсь возможность напрямую преобразовать JSON как результат SQL запроса в объектный тип данных ([Mapping of JSON Data To and From SQL Object Types](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/changes.html#GUID-7D098722-B1ED-4677-97D0-D44565117986)).

Посмотрел [пример из документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/function-JSON_VALUE.html#GUID-622170D8-7BAD-4F5F-86BF-C328451FC3BE__GUID-7412F187-302E-44E2-AAA9-AA86E320D8F3) и решил попробовать:

```
create or replace type partRow is object (name varchar2 (16), qty number);
/
create or replace type partRows is table of partRow;
/
create or replace type itemRow is object (name varchar2 (16), parts partRows);
/
with data as ( 
    select 
        '{"name":"item1", 
        "parts": [{"name": "part1", "qty":"1"}, {"name": "part2", "qty": "2"}]}' item  
    from dual)
select 
    json_value (item, '$.name') itemname,    
    json_value (item, '$.parts[0].name') partname,    
    json_value (item, '$' returning itemRow) item   
from data;
```

Выводит:

```
ITEMNAME PARTNAME ITEM(NAME, PARTS)   
-------- -------- -----------------------
item1    part1    ITEMROW(NULL, NULL)    
                  --------^^^^--^^^^
```

Получаю неинициализированный экземпляр `itemRow`. Скалярные значения `itemname,partname` из JSON, как и в прошлых версиях, получаю как и ожидалось.

Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В главе [16.3 Using JSON_VALUE To Instantiate a User-Defined Object Type Instance](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/function-JSON_VALUE.html#GUID-622170D8-7BAD-4F5F-86BF-C328451FC3BE) указано:

> The field names of the targeted JSON object are compared with the SQL names of the object attributes. [...] If the names do not match (**case insensitively**, by default), then a mismatch error occurs.

Имена полей в JSON должны совпадать с именами атрибутов обьектного типа данных (по умолчанию, без учёта регистра). Но на самом деле, сравнение производится с учётом регистра.
Добавив `ON MISMATCH` клазулу, запрос как в вопросе завершится ошибкой:

```sql
with data as ( 
    select 
        '{"name":"item1", 
        "parts": [{"name": "part1", "qty":"1"}, {"name": "part2", "qty": "2"}]}' item  
    from dual)
select 
    json_value (item, '$' returning itemRow error on mismatch) item   
from data;
```

> ORA-40601: missing data for object type conversion

После заключения всех имён атрибутов в двойные кавычки, чтобы исключить несовпадение имён:

```sql
create or replace type partRow is object ("name" varchar2 (16), "qty" number);
/
create or replace type partRows is table of partRow;
/
create or replace type itemRow is object ("name" varchar2 (16), "parts" partRows);
/
```

Тот же запрос вернётся без ошибки и с ожидаемым результатм:

```
ITEM(name, parts(name, qty))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ITEMROW('item1', PARTROWS(PARTROW('part1', 1), PARTROW('part2', 2)))
```

По видимому имеет место, или новый баг, или ошибка в документации.